# Integrate Alexa Voice Service in our existing product

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to integrate Alexa Voice Service in our existing product. I want to send package notification to specific user using AVS.

I have googled for it and below is the reference:

[AVS Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/notifications-overview.html)

Also I have found 'amazon alexa php' library in github, [amazon-alexa-php](https://github.com/maxbeckers/amazon-alexa-php) Can I use this or not?

**NOTE:** Our application was built on PHP.

**Is it possible with Amazon AVS?**

Comment: Do you have a physical product you want to integrate Alexa into, or do you just want to create a skill that works with your application that sends notifications?

Comment: I want to create a skill that works with my application that sends notifications

Answer (score 0):

The AVS documentation is for people wishing to add Alexa to their device.  Since you are just wanting to create a skill, the github project you specify should be sufficient.

As far as creating notifications, you may have to wait.  As you may have read, as of [here](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/833b9af4-26e6-47d2-a13d-bdbd9a257512/expanded-developer-preview-of-notifications-for-alexa-skills) this feature was introduced in limited preview in Nov 2017, but is now closed.